# e.getWindow().dispose() is not working?

Tags: swing, jframe

I have a main program which calls a `JFrame` to get User information, If a user press submit I am storing the information in POJO and getting it into Main program.

If User clicks on Exit, I want to dispose the `JFrame` and want to exit the main program as well after executing one logging statement in main method.

If I use -

```
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
and
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                e.getWindow().dispose();
            }
        });
```

all the Threads exit immediately and I am not able to execute logging statments in main method.

If I use-

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                e.getWindow().dispose();
            }
        });
```

My main method execute those logging statments but it never exit, It stay silent after executing all the statements.

If I use this -

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine. But is it the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you `dispose` all top-level windows, the JVM should terminate cleanly.

However, there are a few details to make sure, which are detailed on [this page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html):

> Therefore, a stand-alone AWT
>   application that wishes to exit
>   cleanly without calling System.exit
>   must:
>
> - Make sure that all AWT or Swing components are made undisplayable when
>     the application finishes. This can be
>     done by calling Window.dispose on all
>     top-level Windows. See
>     Frame.getFrames.
> - Make sure that no method of AWT event listeners registered by the
>     application with any AWT or Swing
>     component can run into an infinite
>     loop or hang indefinitely. For
>     example, an AWT listener method
>     triggered by some AWT event can post a
>     new AWT event of the same type to the
>     EventQueue. The argument is that
>     methods of AWT event listeners are
>     typically executed on helper threads.

---

If you don't manage to find what keeps the program alive, there can be another way:

-Use the first method you described, with the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`
-Add a ShutdownHook to the runtime, to execute your last logging statements:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //logging statements
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dispose` method only releases system resources. 
To actually close the window you have to call `setVisible(false)`